# How to get the filename part of a path from a shell variable

Tags: environment-variables, filenames, variable, basename

A shell variable holds a path. How does one get its filename portion?

In bash(1), I experimented and found that I can do it with `."${i/*\///}"` where `i` is the name of the environment variable. Such a method is not only ugly but also erroneous in the case where the path does not contain any `/` character.

I'll demonstrate a practical case where such a function is needed. Let's say we want to make a symbolic link for every PDF files in a source directory to the current directory.

```
$ for i in /source/path/*.pdf; do\
  ln -s "$i" ."${i/*\///}"; \
  done
```

Comment: For the example, if you didn't need the dot, just `ln -s "$i"` automatically uses the basename of the target as the link name. Also a nit: that's a shell variable (or shell parameter) but not an environment variable because you didn't `export` it. Within the shell they both work, but if you want to pass information to another program this difference matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`${i##*/}`

This works in Posix shells, including `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, etc. From the standard [POSIX Parameter Expansion section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) of the Posix Shell & Utilities specification:

> **${parameter##[word]}**
>   Remove Largest Prefix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce a
>   pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with
>   the largest portion of the prefix matched by the pattern deleted.

Alternatively, and traditionally, the `basename` command has been used for this purpose.   **Caution:** Performance can become a significant issue because `basename` is implemented as an external command (for example, `/usr/bin/basename`). Because you're performing this inside a loop, you will call an external command for each file.  On a list of 1000 files, this may be the difference between 0.05 seconds (parameter expansion) and 2.0 seconds (`basename` command). But for a list of 10,000 files, it could be the difference between 0.5 seconds (expansion) vs 20 seconds (`basename`).  The difference in performance becomes more extreme as the number of files increases.

For readability as well as performance, you can implement your own `basename` function, for example:

```
mybasename() { echo "${1##*/}"; }
```

(The selection of a better name for the function, and/or the implementation of the full `basename` command line interface, are left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: See also `man basename`, and the [standard POSIX parameter expansions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Comment: I found `basename` easier to read for the next maintainer of my code than the parameter expansions

Answer (score 0):

You can put the path in a variable and use its length-count to get only the desired substring from the full path name, like this:

```
$ pth="/source/path/";
$ for i in $path*.pdf; do \
  ln -s "$i" ./"${i:${#pth}}"; \
  done
```